# Different layout file for different controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

How to make my ZF2 module load other layout file for specific controller ?

Consider you have `IndexController` and `AdminController` in your ZF2 application module and the `IndexController` is using *layout.phtml* but you want to use *adminlayout.phtml* for `AdminController`.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Module {
    public function onBootstrap($e) {
        $em  = $application->getEventManager();

        $em->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function($e) {
            $controller = $e->getTarget();
            if ($controller instanceof Controller\AdminController) {   
                $controller->layout('layout/layoutadmin.phtml');
            } else {
                $controller->layout('layout/layout.phtml');
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

and don't forget to register your new controller by adding this config in your module config file:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        'Application\Controller\Admin' => 'Application\Controller\AdminController',
    ),
),
```

Comment: Just a thought for others who might read this. If you think you need different layouts, there may be something that could be improved in your archetecture. Generally you should only need one layout. If you need two layouts, maybe you should actually have two separate apps (or two separate entry points). Or, maybe you need to use the new ZF2 nested view model system more thoughtfully...just thoughts.

Comment: maybe its good to use A module for index then a module for Admin

Comment: I've fixed your markup. Providing an explanation and pros/cons with this solution would improve this answer a lot. (For instance, why or why not do this instead of manually specify the layout in the controller?)

Comment: @superdweebie I disagree. App might have both frontend and admin that might look totally different and might require different layouts. Or how about authentication pages -> that also might require different layout. So it's completely plausible that 2 controllers need different layouts.

Comment: `$application` is an undefined variable. Where does it come from? Do you mean to use `$e->getApplication()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

other best Solution :

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'YOURMODULENAME' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),

        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        ),
    ),
```

change **YOURMODULENAME** to your module specific name

Comment: I am trying this but is is not working, it really do not care about 'layout/layout'

Comment: u should confirm that router is route to you secondary module for loading then dispatching ...  please upload your code somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding logic to your entire module in the `onBootstrap` method, you can use your controller's `onDispatch` method to simply set the layout for that entire controller.

In your admin controller, add a shortcut at the top:

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
```

Then, use the following `onDispatch` in your controller:

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
{   
    $this->layout()->setTemplate('layout/admin');

    return parent::onDispatch($mvcEvent);
}
```

I believe this solution is better because the code only gets called when the admin controller is called.