# ZF2 addChild ViewModel of another module

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying to add a view of another module in my layout, so I did this:

```
$layoutTestdrive = new ViewModel();
$layoutTestdrive->setTemplate('testdrive6');
$view = new ViewModel();
$view->addChild($layoutTestdrive);
return $view;
```

In my module.config.php I did this:

```
'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver' => array(
'parameters' => array(
'map'  => array(
    'testdrive6' => __DIR__ . '/../../Testdrive/view/layout/testdrive6.phtml'
        ),
    ),
),
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Just remembering, I have two modules, the first module must render a layout from another (Testdrive in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you need to use forward first

```
public function commentAction(){     

    $list = $this->forward()->dispatch('comment_controrller', array('action' => 'list'));
    $add = $this->forward()->dispatch('comment_controrller', array('action' => 'add'));

    $view =  new ViewModel();
    $view->addChild($list, 'list');
    $view->addChild($add, 'add');
    return $view;
}
```

I hope this will help

or if you want just to change template see [Different layout file for different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921329/different-layout-file-for-different-controllerfor)